# How I can flip the collection view for RTL in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview

I have a collection view of 2 columns and 3 rows. I have a button by which I change the language of my whole app from English to Arabic. I **wanted to flip my collection view** as well.

I have successfully flipped the view (means my columns are swapped) but they its cell also got reversed. Can anyone tell me how I can reverse back my cells of collection view?

My code for flipping collection view:

```objectivec
[self.dashBoardCollectionView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
```

Comment: try in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, going `[cell.contentView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];` if the whole collectionview is being flipped as well

Comment: What platform are you working on? iOS 8 or iOS 9? Also, are you using UICollectionViewFlowLayout?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to without transformation of collection view you can flip the view and based on that all subview of that view will flip and you can give a support for RTL.
For that you must need to give trilling and leading constraints horizontally.

**semanticContentAttribute** This property will work for the flip view programmatic and storyboard.
You can use **forceLeftToRight** and **forceRightToLeft** according your requirement.

Comment: This advice doesn't work. It has known drawbacks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130331/uicollectionview-ios-9-issue-on-project-with-rtl-languages-support

Comment: thank you for your solution , it's working with me in cell with arabic mode