# UICollectionView iOS 9 issue on project with RTL languages support

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, ios9, right-to-left

It seems like Apple's new feature of auto-flip interface on RTL languages cause problems when using `UICollectionView`.

I used constraints of type Trailing/Leading for the collection view and they switched their values, as they should, on RTL language.

The problem is that the data actually presented is of the **last** `indexPath` in the collection's data source but the `UIScrollView.contentOffset.x` of the first cell is 0.

A proper behaviour would have been one of the following:

1. Displaying the first `indexPath` correctly and switching the direction of the scroll (to the right) - Best option
2. Not flipping the UI/Constraints so the presented-data / `indexPath` / `scrollView.contentOffset.x` will be synchronised - Option that disabling the RTL support.
3. Presenting cell and data of the last indexPath but fixing the `scrollView.contentOffset.x` to represent the last cell position also.

I guess Apple might fix it sometime in the future but meanwhile we'll have to use workarounds like reversing array and/or scrolling to the last object.

Comment: Could you please file a bug report at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com/)?

Comment: @wakachamo Will do! Thanks for the direct link...

Comment: If you do implement a workaround please scroll the view instead of reversing the array – the bug is in the initial position, not the layout itself.

Comment: Have you had a response from Apple yet? It might also be worth adding this to http://openradar.appspot.com/ to help others track the issue.

Comment: I've been looking at this to come up with a workaround today. The UICollectionview is populated in the right order. So Cell 0 is the top rightmost cell when you're running with RTL languages. The best method I've come up with so far is to use scrollToItemAtIndexPath and giving it item 0 to scroll to. However I'm finding that this isn't 100% reliable.

Comment: @Keab42 as I wrote in the original message - what you did is my first suggested solution and the best for my opinion, but you're right - from some reason it's not 100% consistent.
Will update Apple response to the bug report, if I'll get one.

Comment: Have you got any solution on it

Comment: Same issue on iOS10.

Comment: I have another issue with UICollectionViewFlowLayout and RTL. If I return different sizes for cell, layout is always LTR. :O

Answer (score 29):

I was in a similar situation and found a solution for this. If you are using swift, add the following snippet to your project, and it will make sure that the bounds.origin always follows leading edge of the collection view.

```
extension UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    open override var flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

If you are using Objective-C, just subclass the UICollectionViewLayout class, and override flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection, and return true. Use this subclass as the layout object of your collection view.

Comment: When you are down-voting an answer please show the courtesy of adding a comment on why? That way everyone can learn why this is a bad approach.

Comment: Simple and effective solution.

Comment: This is a must for any UICollectionView with UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Answer (score 5):

I am late but if you don't want to create an extension because it will affect all the collection View in our app. Simply create your own custom class ie.

```
class CustomLayoutForLocalization : UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
    open override var flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection: Bool {
         return true
    } 
}
```

To use this class:

```
// your way of deciding on whether you need to apply this layout may vary depending on use of other tools like LanguageManager_iOS to handle multi-language support
if myCollectionView.effectiveUserInterfaceLayoutDirection == .rightToLeft  {
    let customLayout = CustomLayoutForRTL()
    // if your elements are variable size use the following line
    customLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    // if you want horizontal scroll (single line)
    customLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = customLayout
}
```

Comment: That is the best solution i guess. Thank you Moe

Answer (score 0):

There is one common solution for that problem that works for me, follow below steps to overcome that problem,

- Give the auto layout constraint as per your requirement and then from attribute inspector  change the semantic control  property of the collection view to Force right-to-left from the storyboard.

[image]

- Then open storyboard as source code and find for the “leading” attributes of your relevant collection view and replace that with the “left” and same for the “trailing” replace that with the “right”. Now you almost done.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- now that will give you result as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

extension UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    open override var flipsHorizontallyInOppositeLayoutDirection: Bool {
        return UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirection.rightToLeft
    }
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add a comment explaining your code to others

Answer (score 0):

not pretty though simple math does the trick. (for horizontal collectionview)

```
- (void)switchSemanticDirection:(UISwitch*)sender {
    //TEST switch the semantic direction between LTR and RTL.
    if (sender.isOn) {
        UIView.appearance.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight;
    } else {
        UIView.appearance.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft;
    }

    [self.myContent removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myContent];
    
    //reload your collection view to apply RTL setting programmatically
    [self.list reloadData];
    //position your content into the right offset after flipped RTL
    self.list.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.list.contentSize.width - self.list.contentOffset.x - self.list.bounds.size.width, 
    self.list.contentOffset.y);
}
```